# Convert ListBuffer of Dataframes into one single Dataframe Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, union

I have a ListBuffer of 30 DataFrames with the same fields and I want to 'append' them all at once. What is the best way and most efficient?

```
var result_df_list = new ListBuffer[DataFrame]()
```

I have seen that you can create a Sequence of DF like this:

```
val newDFs = Seq(DF1,DF2,DF3)
newDFs.reduce(_ union _)
```

But how can you achieve this with a ListBuffer?

Comment: for ListBuffer the same as for Seq

Comment: a `ListBuffer` IS a `Seq`

Answer (score 2):

The [reduce method of ListBuffer](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) works as expected.

Running

```
val unioned = result_df_list.reduce(_ union _)
unioned.explain()
```

results in a good looking execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- LocalTableScan [value#1]
:- LocalTableScan [value#5]
+- LocalTableScan [value#9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `reduce()` with ListBuffer.

```
  import spark.implicits._

  var result_df_list = new ListBuffer[DataFrame]()

  val df1 = Seq("1").toDF("value")
  val df2 = Seq("2").toDF("value")
  val df3 = Seq("3").toDF("value")

  result_df_list += df1
  result_df_list += df2
  result_df_list += df3

  val df_united: DataFrame = result_df_list.reduce(_ unionByName _)

  df_united.show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutableList And in mutable list toDF method can be used to convert the object into DataFrame or DataSet

Comment: Might help to post example usages of what you explained.

Answer (score -1):

You can try converting your list buffer to List by invoking toList method on List buffer and then you can use the reduce method.